# What is the best way to check if a specific property in my model has been modified?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, model, dto

I have the following model:

```
[Key]
public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Address { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public int Guests { get; set; }
public DateTime CheckInDate { get; set; }
public DateTime CheckOutDate { get; set; }
public Status BookingStatus { get; set; }
public string Notes { get; set; }
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

I will be creating DTO's from this model but i will still need the `SessionId` property to be included in some of those DTO's.

My question is how do I check the state of the `SessionId` property to make sure that no one has tried to tamper with it?

My worry is that someone could interrupt the post request and try to modify the `SessionId` specifically and mess around with the update to the database.

Ideally I would like to check if the `SessionId` property has been modified and abort the update entirely.

Comment: If you have an endpoint that receives a dto then that's all you know in the endpoint. If you really want to be sure they post the Id they received then you could consider adding  a checksum to the dto. But how likely is it that a Guid can be tampered with successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Using `IsModified` property, you can know whether the value of this property has been modified and should be updated in the database when `SaveChanges()` is called.

Here is the code:

```
var entry = dbContext.Entry(yourEntity);
if (entry.Property(e => e.YourProperty).IsModified)
{
    // YourProperty has been modified
}
```